# How to change the Style of Keyboard button in Card.io Library

Tags: android, card.io

Is there any way to update the design of Keyboard button in `Card.io` Library.

I want to display `TextView` instead of `Button`.

I also need to update the text of `Keyboard` to  `Enter Manually`. Can i change this in Card.io library for Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, card.io does not allow this kind of specialized customization through configuration.  You'll have to fork [the source](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-source), and make the changes yourself.